# The db name in the postgresql-url, was magically changed to uppercase when using spark-jdbc

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, jdbc

I am using `spark-jdbc` to connect to postgresql with a url like: `jdbc:postgresql://ip:port/testdb`.

Then, I get error `PSQLException: FATAL: database "TESTDB" does not exist`. The `testdb` is magically changed to uppercase `TESTDB`. (I'm pretty sure I have lowercase `testdb` inside the url).

Also, I created an uppercase database, e.g. `TESTDB_2`, and made the db_name in the url match the uppercase database, e.g. `jdbc:postgresql://ip:port/TESTDB_2`, and it works fine.

Has anyone had a similar problem? Is there a parameter that is causing this?

- spark-version: 3.3.2
- postgresql-version: 13.1

## update

Since it's the simplest spark code, I didn't think about showing it at first, the scala code is as follows:

```scala
spark
  .read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option(JDBCOptions.JDBC_DRIVER_CLASS, driver())
  .option(JDBCOptions.JDBC_TABLE_NAME, tableName)
  .option(JdbcConfig.USER_KEY, userName)
  .option(JdbcConfig.PASSWORD_KEY, password)
  // problem
  .option(JDBCOptions.JDBC_URL, url)
  // other option
  .option(JDBCOptions.JDBC_UPPER_BOUND, timeRange.endStr)
  .option(JDBCOptions.JDBC_LOWER_BOUND, timeRange.startStr)
  .option(JDBCOptions.JDBC_PARTITION_COLUMN, "c1")
  .option(JDBCOptions.JDBC_NUM_PARTITIONS, numPartitions)
```

## update

I installed a test postgresql (same version) by docker, and everything works fine. Is this due to some setting in the postgresql?

Comment: Could you please share the code you used to connect?

Comment: Hey, @IslamElbanna. I have posted the code. The initial question doesn't include the code because it's the simplest spark code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time of trying, it worked fine after I updated the dependency to `42.2.14`.

But there are still some strange issues found in the attempt:

1. I am using `42.2.11` on local machine. Using raw-JDBC code, it is possible to connect to this database.
2. create a new, version-consistent postgres database. It is also possible to connect through the clustered Spark, and the version is still `42.2.11`.